# DataGridView not binding to my linq queries

Tags: c#, linq, binding, datagridview

I am having a problem binding my DataGridView to a LINQ result that is based off of a strongly typed datatable. Binding Directly to the DataTable works fine. WORKING Example:

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'MYDSDataSet.MYTABLE' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.MYTABLETableAdapter.Fill(this.MYDSDataSet.MYTABLE);

        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = this.MYDSDataSet.MYTABLE;
    }
}
```

Using the following line does NOT work:

```
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = this.MYDSDataSet.MYTABLE.Select(x => x);
```

By working/not working I mean in the first example my datagridview will autogenerate all the columns of the datatable and show me all results. In the second example I will not get any errors but my datagridview will remain completely empty, as if I assigned it no DataSource at all.

From what I have read on this site and others I should have no problems with what I am doing but I can not get the correct results anyway I try. Any ideas? If you need any more info that could help, please let me know.

Edit1: Additional Details.

I tried the following lines, all without success:

```
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = this.MYDSDataSet.Tables["MYTABLE"].AsEnumerable().Select(x => x);
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = this.MYDSDataSet.MYTABLE.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x);
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = this.MYDSDataSet.MYTABLE.Select(x => x).ToList();
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = from x in this.MYDSDataSet.MYTABLE select x;
```

All the results data subsets from above contain the proper data/rowcount when debugging.

My strongly typed datatables are the ones provided by the Visual Studio 2010 Data Source Wizard.

Comment: Just for giggles, does `this.dataGridView1.DataSource = this.MYDSDataSet.MYTABLE.Select(x => x).ToList();` work?

Comment: No, that also gives me no data.

Answer (score 0):

Write it using:

```
this.MYDSDataSet.MYTABLE.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x)
```

DataTable RowCollection does not implement IEnumerable, therefore you can not run query against it unless you convert it using AsEnumerable()

EDIT - Can not add comments yet to discussion in other answer.

Using MYTABLE.Select(x => x) does not work for me in VS2010. It returns the following errors:
Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type. Select() expects a string expression, not lambda.

Comment: My datatable (maybe I am explaining this wrong) already implements IEnumerable so the expression I posted does not present any syntax or other errors. I added the the "AsEnumerable()" call to that line of code as a test and get the same (empty) results.